# MPPT efficency plot

Tags: boost, mppt

I am working on MPPT [P&O] algorithm which is paired with boost converter with a fixed load. I want to plot MPPT efficiency graph and compare it with the system without MPPT, that is just boost converter and the load. I have a DC power supply as the source. I don't know how I can compare efficiency with and without MPPT since my source is DC supply.

Comment: You need to have solar panel datasheet, specification.

Comment: You can easily fake a decent solar panel equivalent with a current soure and several diodes in foward bias stacked in series to give you the correct voltage. Perhaps some series resistance on the output and you are good to go.